# HTML: Div inside Div always bound to parents borders

Tags: html, css

I want to have a div inside a parent div which is not attached to borders of the parent.

Currently, I've following html code in the index.html:

```
<div id="high_prio_container">
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="article_content">
            <h1>
                <strong><span class="text-primary">Some title</span></strong> text</p>
            <a href="#about" class="fa fa-angle-down page-scroll"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS code:

```
#high_prio_container{
background: url(bootstrap/img/c01.jpg);
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
color: #cfcfcf;}

#high_prio_container .overlay{
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.73) 17%, rgba(0,0,0,0.66) 35%, rgba(0,0,0,0.55) 62%, rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.8)), color-stop(17%,rgba(0,0,0,0.73)), color-stop(35%,rgba(0,0,0,0.66)), color-stop(62%,rgba(0,0,0,0.55)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.73) 17%,rgba(0,0,0,0.66) 35%,rgba(0,0,0,0.55) 62%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.73) 17%,rgba(0,0,0,0.66) 35%,rgba(0,0,0,0.55) 62%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.73) 17%,rgba(0,0,0,0.66) 35%,rgba(0,0,0,0.55) 62%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.73) 17%,rgba(0,0,0,0.66) 35%,rgba(0,0,0,0.55) 62%,rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cc000000', endColorstr='#66000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
height: 750px;
background-attachment: fixed;}

.article_content{
margin-top: 30px;
padding: 100px;
margin-left: 5%;
position: relative;
padding: 5% 0 0;
z-index: 1000;
background-color: gray;
opacity: 0.5;}
```

The problem is now that no matter what I do, I can't move the child div (.article_content) away from the borders of the parent container. If I use margin, I get a black space (size of margin) between the child and parent div.

I hope that this is somehow understandable. I made this pic to illustrate the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called **[margin-collapsing](https://css-tricks.com/what-you-should-know-about-collapsing-margins/)**. There are many ways you can solve it.

One way is use following css:

```
#high_prio_container .overlay{
  padding: 0.1px;
}
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/91qw68m9/)**

Another way it give `position: absolute;`  to `.article_content`

Or

`display: inline-block;` to `.article_content`

Answer (score 1):

What would work is working with padding in the parent container (or even the child container if you have a transparent background). So you could use:

```
.overlay {
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```